# Html link to a folder not a file on ftp server. But this folder has html?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a simple website that I can reach through ftp. There is a login page, what is written in .php. I don't know php at all. My problem is: 
In the homepage .html file, a link only points to a folder (not a .html file or something) on the ftp server like this:

```
<a href="login/">
```

[image]

And it goes to a page that has html(pictures):

[image]

[image]

There is no html file on ftp server in the "login" folder. But I have to edit that login page. But my mind in now blown :D I know its kinda newbie question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any `.htaccess` involved such that requests are internally rewritten?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the text of any source code rather than images of source code. Images are not accessible, are hard to read on smaller screen sizes, and are not searchable. Once you paste the source code in there is a button that will indent it by four spaces and cause it to render as code.

Answer (score 0):

That is how server folder structure works.

I am assuming there's either a `index.php` or `index.html` in the `/login` folder.

You don't have to point to the file directly for index files. Your server will hand out the `index` file automatically.

For example, imagine this is my login folder:

```
/login
  + index.php
  + process.php
  + logout.php
```

If you navigate to `/login` it will automatically hand you `index.php`. If you want to logout, then you would send them to `/login/logout.php`.

Think of a book, it always starts with an index, which will guide you through the book. The same way the index page of a site. It guides you through that site.

Comment: Thx, Samuel! I'm not commented, answered instead, so i can paste code in.

Comment: @Szilveszter You can use html mark up within PHP. Whatever is not between `<?php ?>` is read as plain/text or html depending on your encoding.

Comment: Notice this line: `switch ($_REQUEST["page"])`... Once you're logged in, it will display the contents of whatever the switch case determines. One of them would be: `include("editprofile.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. It has a index.php file, but...i dont get it. How is this possible that a php file contains html? This is the index.php(below):

But i dont see the html elements, that shows on the page.

```html
<?
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once("config.php");
require_once("libs/functions.php");

if (!empty($_POST["tluser"]) && !empty($_POST["tlpw"])) {
 $sql = "
  SELECT a.*, b.travel_agency_name 
  FROM tourleader a, travel_agency b 
  WHERE 
  a.travel_agency_id = b.travel_agency_id AND 
  a.tourleader_status = 1 AND 
  a.tourleader_user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tluser"])."' AND 
  a.tourleader_password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tlpw"])."'
 ";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
 if (!empty($row["tourleader_id"])) {
  $sql_phone = "SELECT * FROM tourleader_phone WHERE tourleader_id = '".$row["tourleader_id"]."' ORDER BY phone_id";
  $res_phone = mysql_query($sql_phone);
  $list_phone = array();
  while ($row_phone = mysql_fetch_array($res_phone)) {
   if ($row_phone["phone_default"] == 1) {
    $row["tourleader_phone_default"] = $row_phone["phone_number"];
    $row["tourleader_phone_type"] = $row_phone["phone_type"];
    $row["tourleader_phone_user"] = $row_phone["phone_user"];
   }
   array_push($list_phone, $row_phone);
  }
  $row["tourleader_phone"] = $list_phone;
  $sql_nation = "SELECT nation_name FROM tourleader_nation WHERE nation_id = '".$row["nation_id"]."'";
  $res_nation = mysql_query($sql_nation);
  $row_nation = mysql_fetch_row($res_nation);
  $row["tourleader_nation"] = $row_nation[0];
  $_SESSION["tourleader_id"] = $row["tourleader_id"];
  $_SESSION["tourleader_data"] = $row;
  header("Location:index.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id());
  die();
 } else {
  $_SESSION["tourleader_id"] = 0;
  $smarty->assign("loginerror", 1);
 }
}
if (empty($_SESSION["tourleader_id"])) {
 $smarty->assign("action", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
 $smarty->assign("tpl", "auth.tpl");
} else {
 $smarty->assign("tourleader_id", $_SESSION["tourleader_id"]);
 $smarty->assign("tourleader_data", $_SESSION["tourleader_data"]);
 // Nyelvi beallitasok
 $lang = $_SESSION["tourleader_data"]["lang_id"];
 include("langs/".$lang.".php");
 $smarty->assign("translatemap", $translatemap);

 $_REQUEST["page"] = (isset($_REQUEST["page"])) ? $_REQUEST["page"] : ""; 
 $_REQUEST["action"] = (isset($_REQUEST["action"])) ? $_REQUEST["action"] : ""; 

 switch ($_REQUEST["page"]) {
  case "logout" :
   unset($_SESSION["tourleader_id"]);
   unset($_SESSION["tourleader_data"]);
   header("Location:index.php");
  break;
  
  case "requestplist" :
   include("requestplist.php");
  break;
  
  case "editprofile" :
   include("editprofile.php");
  break;
  
  case "vieworder" :
   include("vieworder.php");
  break;

  case "neworder" :
   include("neworder.php");
  break;
  
  default :
   $list = getactiveorders($_SESSION["tourleader_id"]);
   $smarty->assign("list", $list);
   $smarty->assign("tpl", "mainpage.tpl");
  break;
 }
}
$smarty->display("index.tpl");

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
*/
?>
```

Comment: And there is no index.html in the "login" folder :\

Comment: You don't need an `index.html`... As long as you have a `index.php`, it's essentially the same thing. Except `php` can run `php` code between `<?php ?>` tags. Everything else will be seen as html.